# How can I concat and fill at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have three data frames:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = DataFrame([
    [1],
    [3],
    [4]
],
    index=[1, 3, 4],
    columns=['value1']
)

df2 = DataFrame([
    [5],
    [6],
    [7],
],
    index=[5, 6, 7],
    columns=['value2']
)

df3 = DataFrame([
    [5, 9],
    [6, 10],
    [7, 11],
    [8, 12]
],
    index=[5, 6, 7, 8],
    columns=['value1', 'value2']
)
```

Using

```
concat([df1, df2, df3], sort=True, axis=1)
```

will now give me

```
   value1  value2  value1  value2
1     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
3     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
4     4.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
5     NaN     5.0     5.0     9.0
6     NaN     6.0     6.0    10.0
7     NaN     7.0     7.0    11.0
8     NaN     NaN     8.0    12.0
```

Now, how can I get to the result

```
   value1  value2
1     1.0     NaN
3     3.0     NaN
4     4.0     NaN
5     5.0     5.0
6     5.0     6.0
7     7.0     7.0
8     8.0     12.0
```

In other words, for columns of the same name, how can I merge them "to the left"? I'm looking for a generic solution, which can accept any number of multiple columns with the same name (as well as also having column names that only occur once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df3)
print (df)
   value1  value2
1     1.0     NaN
3     3.0     NaN
4     4.0     NaN
5     5.0     5.0
6     6.0     6.0
7     7.0     7.0
8     8.0    12.0
```

More general solution working with `list of DataFrames` is use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df = reduce(lambda l,r: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(l,r), dfs)
```

Comment: Great. Had to add `DataFrame()` as an initial value (third argument to `reduce`).